# How to list all variables of an object in ActionScript 3 in declaration order?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5

i want to put all variables of an object into ByteArray in declaration order.
the object can be a extends one.
here is my code:

---

```
    private static function getVariables( packet:*): Array
    {
        var vars:Array = new Array();           
        var description:XML = describeType(packet);
        Alert.show(description);
        var descriptionList:XMLList = 
            description..accessor.(@access != "writeonly") + description..variable;
        for each ( var info:XML in descriptionList )
        {
            vars.push( { name: info.@name, type: info.@type,
                pos: uint(info..metadata..arg.@value) } );
        }
        vars.sortOn( "pos", Array.DESCENDING );
        return vars;
    }

    public static function print():void
    {
        var o:C = new C();
        var description:XML = describeType(o);
        Alert.show(description);
    }

    public class A
    {
       public var a_of_A:int;
       public var b_of_A:int;
    }
    public class B extends A
    {
       public var i_of_B:int;
       public var j_of_B:int;
    }
    public class C extends B
    {
       public var d_of_C:int;
       public var e_of_C:int;
    }

<type name="packet::C" base="packet::B" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
    <extendsClass type="packet::B"/>
    <extendsClass type="packet::A"/>
    <extendsClass type="Object"/>
    <variable name="j_of_B" type="int">
      <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
        <arg key="pos" value="110"/>
      </metadata>
    </variable>
    <variable name="i_of_B" type="int">
      <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
        <arg key="pos" value="84"/>
      </metadata>
    </variable>
    <variable name="e_of_C" type="int">
      <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
        <arg key="pos" value="110"/>
      </metadata>
    </variable>
    <variable name="b_of_A" type="int">
      <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
        <arg key="pos" value="81"/>
      </metadata>
    </variable>
    <variable name="d_of_C" type="int">
      <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
        <arg key="pos" value="84"/>
      </metadata>
    </variable>
    <variable name="a_of_A" type="int">
      <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
        <arg key="pos" value="55"/>
      </metadata>
    </variable>
    <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
      <arg key="pos" value="54"/>
    </metadata>
  </type>
```

what does the "pos" for ?

i try to print the xml, but i can not find the meaning of "pos"....

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn()

```
AS3 function sortOn(fieldName:Object, options:Object = null):Array
```

So "pos" is the field name.

Comment: but "pos" seems like doesn't mean the declaration order

Comment: the `describeType` method returns an xml with information about your class. Try to print out its output.

Comment: i post the xml, can not figure it out.